# Regex Group Slashes

Tags: regex

I have a string:

`/1/2/3/anystring as follows here even forward slashes/////`

how can i capture the groups

`(1) (2) (3) (anystring as follows here even forward slashes/////)`

or conditionally if (2) or (3) cannot be captured then capture one (1) or (1)/(2) or (1)(2)(3) or all

i have tried

`^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)`

but it doesn't capture `/1/2/` or `/1/` or `/1/2/3/`.

Comment: Instead of `(.*)`, try `(.*?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var str = "/1/2/3/anystring as follows here even forward slashes/////";
str.replace(/\/(([\w\s]|\/+$)+)/g,"($1)");
```

"(1)(2)(3)(anystring as follows here even forward slashes/////)"

Answer (score 1):

Change your *greedy* quantifiers `.*` to *reluctant* quantifiers `.*?`:

```
^/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/bFO7uoKsNt).

Comment: thanks but when i try matching `/1/2/3/anystring///`, i doesn't capture the `anystring///`i works with `/1/anystring///` but i captures only `/1/anystring//` missing out the one `/`

Comment: I thought your question only asked to capture "1", "2" and "3". It captures the rest now too

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
^(?:/(.*?))?(?:/(.*?))?(?:/(.*?)/).*/////
```

Just use quantifier `?` which stands for quantity 0 or 1 and non-greedy quantifier `*?` to perform non-greedy match.

See: [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cU6hS9/2)

Comment: It captured. Have you check my demo?

Comment: Please make it clear about the pattern how many slashes on the tail of your string?